Does the changed wording for the arcane ward subclass feature (lvl3) imply that recharging it with the armor of shadows is no longer possible?
In the previous Player's Handbook (2014), the text for recharging the Arcane Ward was:

"Whenever you cast an abjuration spell of 1st level or higher, the
ward regains a number of hit points equal to twice the level of the
spell."

By this, it was possible to charge Arcane Ward by using Armor of Shadows repeatedly to cast Mage Armor without using a spell slot (see this post for details), with the exact wording of Armor of Shadows being:

You can cast Mage Armor on yourself without expending a spell slot.

Although sometimes frowned upon by DMs, this was in general an accepted and widespread game mechanic (see for example this reddit thread).
Now however, the wording of arcane ward has slightly changed, it now says (PHB 24, p.172)

"Whenever you cast an Abjuration spell with a spell slot, the ward
regains a number of Hit Points equal to twice the level of the spell
slot."

RAW that means that the recharge mechanic doesn't work anymore, right?

Yes, you're right
Arcane Ward states (emphasis added):

Whenever you cast an Abjuration spell with a spell slot, the ward
regains a number of Hit Points equal to twice the level of the spell
slot. Alternatively, as a Bonus Action, you can expend a spell slot,
and the ward regains a number of Hit Points equal to twice the level
of the spell slot expended.

If you cast a spell without a spell slot, for example thanks to certain traits, features or feats giving you prepared spells that you can cast without using a spell slot, or thanks to Magic Items, then Arcane Ward is not affected.

Many Abjuration Wizard's won't like that ...

@Quantumwhisp: It's a pretty obvious exploit of a rules interaction; makes sense they'd close that loophole.  Arcane Ward is (I assume) supposed to be balanced around characters not being able to refill it for free given a couple minutes where they can spam-cast.  I'd hope any existing characters that took Eldritch Adept for that reason would be allowed to re-spec that ASI in campaigns that are switching from 2014 to 2024 and forcing all characters to use new rules for everything possible.  Because that would indeed suck to be stuck with a low-powered invocation choice from Eldritch Adept.

18th-level Abjurers could choose mage armor as one of their signature spells in 2014, to exploit arcane ward without needing a warlock invocation.  The 2024 change of course disables that trick, too, and there's more of an argument that wasn't an "exploit", just a powerful high-level feature.  (Swapping a signature spell to something else is even easier in 2024 than in 2014, just after any long rest, vs. needing 8 hours in study.)
